# Define function in a Ballerina service

Tags: service, ballerina

Please check the below code.

```
import ballerina/http;

service / on new http:Listener(9091) {
    function getMessage() returns string {
        return "custom message";
    }
    resource function get greeting() returns string {
        return getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here we have defined a function called `getMessage` and we get an `undefined` error when the function is used.

How do we solve that?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `self` to refer to members of the object within the Ballerina object.

```
import ballerina/http;

service / on new http:Listener(9091) {
    function getMessage() returns string {
        return "custom message";
    }
    resource function get greeting() returns string {
        return self.getMessage(); // use self
    }
}
```